# White space at the bottom of a web page on low browser resolutions (CSS-Grid layout)

Tags: html, css, font-size, css-grid

I've been trying to make a simple site layout using CSS-Grid.
Everything is working just fine and is responsive, but when I minimize my browser to really small resolutions scroll bars appears and the css-grid stops stretching over the entire page height, causing a blank white space on the bottom.

To see what I mean, simply run the snippet I've inserted as it opens in a low height window. I've also uploaded pictures of how it shows on my browser.

How it shows on normal height:

[image]

What happens when I reduce height:

[image]

I tried playing around with `overflow` and `min-height`, but couldn't work it out. It is not really a critical issue but I'm really interested just to understand why it happens. Thanks!

```css
body, html{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container-1{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 8% 70% auto 8% ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header1 header1 header1 header1"
  "Cover Cover Cover Cover"
  "Project Project Project Project"
  "Footer Footer Footer Footer"
}

.header1{
  grid-area: header1;
}

.cover{
  grid-area: Cover;
}

.Project{
  grid-area: Project;
}

.Footer{
  grid-area: Footer;
}

.zone {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/***********************************************************************
 *  Green Background
 **********************************************************************/
.green{
    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Red Background
 **********************************************************************/
.red{
    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Yellow Background
 **********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Blue Background
 **********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSS Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-1">
      <div class="header1 zone green">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="cover zone red">
          Cover
      </div>
      <div class="Project zone blue">
        Projects
      </div>
      <div class="Footer zone yellow">
        Footer
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font is too large for the last row height and it spills out of it's container.

One of the solutions is to change the last row size to `1fr`:

```css
body, html{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container-1{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 8% 70% auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header1 header1 header1 header1"
  "Cover Cover Cover Cover"
  "Project Project Project Project"
  "Footer Footer Footer Footer"
}

.header1{
  grid-area: header1;
}

.cover{
  grid-area: Cover;
}

.Project{
  grid-area: Project;
}

.Footer{
  grid-area: Footer;
}

.zone {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/***********************************************************************
 *  Green Background
 **********************************************************************/
.green{
    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Red Background
 **********************************************************************/
.red{
    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Yellow Background
 **********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Blue Background
 **********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSS Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-1">
      <div class="header1 zone green">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="cover zone red">
          Cover
      </div>
      <div class="Project zone blue">
        Projects
      </div>
      <div class="Footer zone yellow">
        Footer
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your viewport is too small to fit your *header* and *footer*, your text size is overflowing - as a *quick fix* you can add `overflow: hidden` to `zone` to *solve* this in smaller screens - see demo below:

```css
body, html{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container-1{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 8% 70% auto 8% ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header1 header1 header1 header1"
  "Cover Cover Cover Cover"
  "Project Project Project Project"
  "Footer Footer Footer Footer"
}

.header1{
  grid-area: header1;
}

.cover{
  grid-area: Cover;
}

.Project{
  grid-area: Project;
}

.Footer{
  grid-area: Footer;
}

.zone {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    overflow: hidden; /* ADDED */
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/***********************************************************************
 *  Green Background
 **********************************************************************/
.green{
    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Red Background
 **********************************************************************/
.red{
    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Yellow Background
 **********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Blue Background
 **********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSS Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-1">
      <div class="header1 zone green">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="cover zone red">
          Cover
      </div>
      <div class="Project zone blue">
        Projects
      </div>
      <div class="Footer zone yellow">
        Footer
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Because the text is *overflowing* the elements is not very useful, you need to adjust the heights of your *header* and *footer* in your `grid-template-rows` to a value something like `grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr auto 3em`:

```css
body, html{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container-1{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr auto 3em; /* CHANGED */
  grid-template-areas:
  "header1 header1 header1 header1"
  "Cover Cover Cover Cover"
  "Project Project Project Project"
  "Footer Footer Footer Footer"
}

.header1{
  grid-area: header1;
}

.cover{
  grid-area: Cover;
}

.Project{
  grid-area: Project;
}

.Footer{
  grid-area: Footer;
}

.zone {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/*https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-shiny-css-buttons*/
/***********************************************************************
 *  Green Background
 **********************************************************************/
.green{
    background: #56B870; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#56B870), color-stop(100%,#a5c956)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%,#a5c956 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Red Background
 **********************************************************************/
.red{
    background: #C655BE; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C655BE), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #C655BE 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Yellow Background
 **********************************************************************/
.yellow{
    background: #F3AAAA; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%, #febf04 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3AAAA), color-stop(100%,#febf04)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F3AAAA 0%,#febf04 100%); /* W3C */
}

/***********************************************************************
 *  Blue Background
 **********************************************************************/
.blue{
    background: #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%, #60abf8 44%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7abcff), color-stop(44%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7abcff 0%,#60abf8 44%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSS Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-1">
      <div class="header1 zone green">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="cover zone red">
          Cover
      </div>
      <div class="Project zone blue">
        Projects
      </div>
      <div class="Footer zone yellow">
        Footer
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried using overflow: hidden before but for some reason, it didn't work, I probably used it wrong though. Thanks!

Comment: @rzk666 instead of using *percentages* it'd better if you use something like `grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr auto 3em` - this reflects the `font-size` that you are using and is more relevant to your layout...